# Shifting the erroneous horizontal position of SubItemImages in a Delphi TListView?

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-xe2, subitem

In a Delphi `TListView`, is it possible to shift the erroneous horizontal position of SubItemImages, as they are drawn too far left? Something like this, for example (pseudo-code, which just shows the intention):

```
x := MyListView.Items[i].SubItemImages[2].HorizontalPosition;
MyListView.Items[i].SubItemImages[2].HorizontalPosition := x + 2;
```

This screenshot which shows the bug:

[image]

Comment: For clarification: The question is not about the pseudo-code example. The question is: How can I shift the horizontal position of SubItemImages?

Comment: That's not clear (you mention pseudo-code, but bring more attention to that pseudo-code with it's formatting than the disclaimer attracts), and your pseudo-code could mislead future readers of this question; that's why I specifically mentioned why it wouldn't work in my answer (which also provides the info you're looking for as well).

Comment: You're going to need to draw the sub items yourself to get that level of control.

Comment: Is what you're looking for is to shift/indent the image in a subitem without drawing the contents yourself? If so, what will happen with possible text, will it also shift by the same amount? Should this be restricted with only canvas methods (in an ondraw event handler), or are GDI calls allowed?

Comment: This is all due to Delphi's bug in TListView: SubItemImages are cut off by 1-2 pixel on the left side when 'ListView.GridLines = True': (http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/3360/delphitlistviewgrid.png)
The distance between SubItemImage and SubItem is much larger than the distance between Item.Caption and Item.Image, which looks very ugly.
So I am looking for a workaround to somehow shift the SubItemImages a few pixel to the right side.

Comment: @user - That is a very clear description of the problem, very much to the point than the question itself.. The precise answer to that problem is in David's comment unfortunately. I had some possible solution in my mind to shift the entire contents of a subitem, but there's no way you can shift only the image without drawing all yourself. BTW, I don't think Delphi have got anything to do with that bug.

Comment: It surely won't be a Delphi bug. What's more, why did you wait 24 hours before telling us the real information. Never start with the solution. Always start by explaining the problem. Please edit the question to include this new detail.

Answer (score 3):

No. [`TListItem.SubItemImages`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem.SubItemImages) is an integer, and integers don't have horizontal positions.

```
property SubItemImages[Index: Integer]: Integer read GetSubItemImage 
  write SetSubItemImage;
```

You can find this out by looking at the VCL source code, in this case in the `ComCtrls` unit. The relevant code is in `TListItem.GetSubItemImage` (code from XE3 shown below, but it's the same as the code in previous versions of Delphi).

```
function TListItem.GetSubItemImage(Index: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := TSubItems(FSubItems).ImageIndex[Index];
end;
```

As far as I can see from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), there's no way to change that image's location. The columns are created by sending the underlying Windows `ListView` control an [`LVCOLUMN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) record (structure) for each column's definition, which has no location information available to assign. It has a flag to set the image right-aligned (`LVCFMT_BITMAP_ON_RIGHT`), but nothing else to allow you to actually position the image to a specific location in the column.

Comment: I was expecting such a comment. Therefore I explicitly wrote "PSEUDO-CODE".
Now, is there a way to shift the horizontal position of EXISTING SubItemImages?

Comment: I answered that, but I've edited to clarify. (`SubItemImages` is a list of indexes into a `TImageList`, and `TImageList` doesn't have a positioning coordinate either, and the `ListView` common control doesn't seem to allow this positioning either. I've added links to the docs related to that.

Comment: *" **iIndent** [..] Note that this field is supported only for items. Attempting to set subitem indentation will cause the calling function to fail."* ([LVITEM structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774760(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: @Sertac: Thanks. :-) I was looking for a specific citation, but you found it first.

Comment: @Ken - You're welcome! Actually it may not be considered exactly as a proof for there is no built-in indentation support for sub items, as it actually just proves you can't do this with `ListView_SetItem`. There is an inherent problem looking for a citation for something that does not exist.., it may not exist. I guess the simple answer to the question *"Are you REALLY sure?"* is **Yes!**.

Comment: Maybe there is a way in OnAdvancedCustomDrawSubItem? Couldn't the SubItemImage be "moved" with Canvas methods inside this event handler?

Comment: @user - Well, you can draw anything you like with custom drawing. But the pseude-code in the question suggests that you're looking for something like setting a property.

Comment: @user1580348: Well, custom drawing is not what this question asked. If you have a separate question about that topic, please post it as one. You asked here about setting a property, and the answer to that question is a solid **no**. And yes, I'm **REALLY** sure about that answer. :-)

Comment: Why do you keep ignoring my question? I did NOT ask about setting a property. AGAIN: My question clearly was: "Shifting horizontal position of existing SubItemImages in a ListView?" The proposed pseudo-code was only to show the INTENTION! Please read my question again!

Comment: Why do you keep ignoring my ANSWER? And SHOUTING at me? The ANSWER, once AGAIN, is NO. There is NO way built in to the ListView that will allow you to move the subimages to a position you want. I'm not sure what PART of NO you're having trouble UNDERSTANDING. If you'd like to CHANGE YOUR QUESTION so it doesn't ask how to do it by SETTING a PROPERTY, please feel free to EDIT. (And perhaps NOW you can STOP SHOUTING?) Or maybe you could **SHOUT** louder by putting it in **BOLD** or ***BOLD ITALICS*** instead.

Comment: I'm not shouting, I just explain facts. Again: I did not ask for a "built in way in the ListView". Again, my question was: "Shifting horizontal position of existing SubItemImages in a ListView?" Do you read any words "built in"? Please tell me where you read these words. Thank you for your efforts!